# Blank data frames in r studio viewer

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

I am using RStudio Version 1.0.143 with R version 3.4.1 on a Microsoft Windows 10 64 bit System. 
Until yesterday everything worked fine. But suddenly my Viewer does not display data frames anymore. It only shows blank rows and columns.
I already reinstalled both R and R Studio without success. Also a randomly created data frame was not displayed.
When using 
utils::View(a)
a new window opens and the data frame including the data is displayed. 
I did not receive any error message and it started while working on RStudio, so not between any system updates.

I searched the web and found on entry with the same problem but without solution. What went wrong and how can I change it back to the normal setting?

I would be very thankful for any help.
Best regards
Sven

[Blank rows and columns in R data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qgsb.png)

Comment: Is your data empty when you're typing `str(a)` for example ?

Comment: No it is not. I can also use all regular commands on the data frames. I just cannot see the data in the viewer.

Comment: Try to get help from there : https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200321257-Running-a-Diagnostics-Report

Comment: I just found, that yesterday my java updated, might that be a possible reason?

Comment: @S.R. I have the exact same setup, just updated Java to check, and I have no problems. So unlikely that the problem is Java. Do you see anything when trying `View(iris)`? Or can you give us the code constructing the random data frame? Then I can check whether the problem might be specific to the type of input.

Comment: View(iris) gives me the same blank data frame. This is the code for the random data frame: data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE))).

Comment: @Joris Meys What I'd liked to add: Normally I am using R at work. Yesterday night I wanted to do some work at home and suddenly I saw my Data frames in the Viewer again. I was quite happy since I thought the problem somehow solved itself. Nevertheless, starting R Studio at work this morning, again I was not able to see the data frames :/. Please don't get me wrong here: It is the same Laptop I was using at work and at home, so it cannot refer to that.

Makes it all even stranger.

Comment: That's indeed very strange, no clue what this might cause. Do you use VPN or so at work by any chance? I know RStudio is actually partly based on web technology under the hood, and the only difference between home and office I can think of, is the way you link to a network. But that doesn't solve your problem though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try right clicking on a cell in the first column in your table view and choose inspect.

In the Web Inspector, scroll down to where it says

```
body {
font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', 'Lucida Grande', 'Segoe UI', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

Drag your mouse over that and disable it. Your table values should appear again.

This is part of the gridstyles.css.

If that fixes it for you, consider editing that css file at C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\grid\gridstyles.css

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. It acutally fixed my problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: It fixes it for me too, but could one elaborate, why this issue is caused? Am I missing a font on my system (Win7)

Comment: just figured out, that the first entry `'Lucida Sans', ` is missing. When I add it to that line in the file, it works again.